# What is the difference between PNO scan and Scheduled Scanning in WLAN?

Tags: linux-device-driver, android-wifi

In wpa_supplicant, if the driver has the capability to support scheduled scan, it triggers a scheduled scan to driver else a PNO scan to the driver when host is about to got to SUSPEND mode.
I am trying to understand what is the difference between the two and what are other use cases where scheduled scan will be used.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

scheduled scan can be triggered by framework depends upon features as like G-scan(google feature of periodic scanning), PNO scan is one such generally triggered when a connection is lost and have to reconnect in suspend state.